# Has Made in Space any track record growing specialty crystals in microgravity before? ("Industrial Crystal Facility" to fly this year)

Tags: optical, business, reduced-gravity-manufacturing, optical-communication, optical-fiber

Ars Technica's [There are an insane amount of cool space things happening in 2021](https://arstechnica.com/science/2021/01/there-are-an-insane-amount-of-cool-space-things-happening-in-2021/) mentions:

> This year, Made in Space's "[Industrial Crystal Facility](https://madeinspace.us/capabilities-and-technology/industrial-crystal-facility/)" should also fly to space. This will serve as a platform to explore whether industrial crystals can be grown in microgravity to larger sizes, or with an improved quality compared to those on Earth. If you're interested in the commercialization of low-Earth orbit, this is one area to watch.

That Made in Space link says:

> Applications
>
> Microgravity production holds the potential for room-temperature production of nonlinear optic (NLO) materials for high-energy applications with size and quality undiminished by the effects of sedimentation and convection. NLOs enable frequency shifting, optical modulation, optical switching, optical logic, and optical memory functions in opto-electronics. Opto-electronic systems enable the use of quantum mechanical effects of light to create new computational operations.
>
> Intended applications include NLO single crystals and other large material formulations, such as bulk single-crystal thin films and high-temperature optical fiber. The benefits of these mirco-gravity crystals include ultra-fast optical switches, optical waveguides, optical circuit lithography, high-efficiency ultraviolet light production, and terahertz wave sensors

Many of us have used a [nonlinear optical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics) (NLO) material in the classic green laser pointer, where an infrared diode laser pumped an infrared crystal laser emitting 1064 nm light, which was then frequency doubled into a 532 nm green laser beam. ([Diode-pumped solid-state laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode-pumped_solid-state_laser))

**Question:** Has Made in Space any track record growing specialty crystals in microgravity before? Have they done experiments growing nonlinear optical crystals at room temperature on the the ISS before?

For example, have there been previous demonstrations in microgravity aboard spacecraft or in aircraft showing that this "room-temperature production" process works for NLO materials; that crystal growth even happens and that it is higher quality and that this was due to reducing the "effects of sedimentation and convection"?

While it may be known that *some crystals* grow better in microgravity, the ones I've heard of are very large organic molecules (e.g. proteins) where gravity can be a serious problem. NLO materials, especially those for "high-energy applications" *I am guessing* are likely to be smaller inorganic unit cell crystals.

Comment: @RussellBorogove yes indeed, one only need to find investors willing to be convinced that something might lead to something that might lead to something that might in some way make money or yield intellectual property that might.

Comment: you've already mentioned their optical fibres in other posts, so I guess you already know the answer to this one.

Comment: @JCRM I've written more than 3,000 posts over several years in this SE site alone. At 300 words per post *that's about one million words!* Why would you guess that I would be able to recall all of that at any moment? (I've modified the question a bit based on (at)RussellBorogove's comment and some difficult to discern discontent expressed in your comment)

Comment: @RussellBorogove I've updated the question; no more "think"

Comment: In russian about industrial crystals in space. Review article on achievements for 1990. It is difficult to judge the results if the "numbers" are not indicated.  According to the article, unexpected problems arose in the early stages of production. http://epizodsspace.airbase.ru/bibl/nauka-v-ussr/1990/shagi.html

Comment: "explore", "potential", "intended"... It looks like the whole goal of that mission is precisely to experiment and determine if their assumptions are true... If they are, possibly a lot of $$$ in sight for them and their investor. If they aren't, they'll probably find something else to "make in space".

Comment: @jcaron that sounds likely. "...holds the potential for..." means almost nothing really. I think that if it can be found that there were no tests of "room-temperature production of nonlinear optic (NLO) materials" in microgravity in space, the question will have at least a partial answer. That shouldn't be impossible to check.